# passport is logging me out anytime I minimize the screen

Tags: node.js, passport.js

Passport is logging me out anytime I minimizing the screen.

Here is my source code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
    secret: "Our little secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        secure: false,
        maxAge: 3600000
    }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: Will it definitely happen when you minimize the window?

Comment: Definitely happened

Comment: Then this is not an issue with your code. This is with your browser. Can you check whether or not site data clears when you minimize the browser window?